# Get a PsiClass from a class name

Tags: intellij-idea, static-analysis, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to determine if a method is available on a particular class, using

```
psiClass.getMethods();
// filter methods down to the one I'm looking for
```

I can get a `PsiType` using the FQCN, but don't know how to get the `PsiClass` from the `PsiType`, or if that's entirely the wrong way.

```
String className = "com.foo.Bar";
PsiType type = PsiElementFactory.SERVICE.getInstance(project).getTypeByFQClassName(className);
```

What is the right way to get a class, given its FQCN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [the documentation](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/psi_cookbook.html), the right way to find a `PsiClass` by qualified name is to use `JavaPsiFacade.findClass()`.